# $compile does not apply the expression of template string on link function of directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I am new with AngularJs and I got trouble in the following code.

```
return {
        require: ['^myElement'],
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
            scope.xa = 'This is xa'
                    scope.$on('form:submit', function() {

                        scope.xb = 'This is xb'
                        var data = $compile( '<p>{{xa}} {{xb}}</p>' )( scope );
                        console.log(data.html()); //result is '{{xa}} {{xb}}', the expressions were not applied
                    });
                }
}
```

The output which I got from the log is `'{{xa}} {{xb}}'`, it should have to be

```
'This is xa This is xb'
```

Here is the [plunker source code](http://plnkr.co/edit/tPc61wxUroOc8xHPaeEx?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a modal dialog box to display a message that would be compiled from a template cache. In my original sample, it just returned the raw string from the template regardless whatever I did. 
The workaround is I need to put the compile code into the directive's `controller` section like below instead of `link` section, then I return the compiled string into a variable such $scope.data and I will use it on the `link`

```
controller: function ( $scope, $element, $attrs ) {

        var vsTemplate = $templateCache.get($attrs.templateUrl)
        $scope.data= $compile(vsTemplate)($scope)
},
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
      dialogs.notify('Errors Summary', $scope.data)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely angularjs hasn't had time to run the $digest cycle and it hasn't interpreted the variables because if you append the result to an html element it works :

http://plnkr.co/edit/N7TfEC1R1qNcPxY6eXNG?p=preview

```
scope.$on('form:submit', function() {
  scope.xb = 'This is xb'
  var data = $compile( '<p>{{xa}} {{xb}}</p>' )( scope );
  element.append(data);
});
```